# how to write a php regex for a string that start with one character followed by 6 numbers

Tags: php, regex

I would like to write a regex to match a string starts with one character followed by 6 numbers.
below is what i write:

```
$pattern  = '/^[a-z][0-9]{6}$/'
```

I am not sure if it is correct. If it is not correct, how to write the regex?

Comment: Why you don't test it?

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte something wrong when i test it, and cant find why. so i suspect if the regex is not correct and cause the problem when i test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That says it starts with one lower case letter, if you want to cover upper case too, then:

```
$pattern  = '/^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}$/'
```